# R: Lookup in List based on Dynamic index

Tags: r

I set up the status in my config as

```
> config$status
[1] "development"
```

And I have a directory config list, as in

```
> config$lib.path
$production
[1] "packages"

$development
[1] "packrat/lib/x86_64-apple-darwin10.8.0/3.1.1"
```

How can I dynamically specify the lib path using `config$status`? I would like to do something along the lines of (following somewhat PHP notation, which gives syntax error here)

```
> config$lib.path${config$status}
"packrat/lib/x86_64-apple-darwin10.8.0/3.1.1"
```

I did search effort, but all solutions I found referred to dynamically *generating* variables using `assign()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have

```
config <- list(
    status="development",
    lib.path = list(
        development="packrat/lib/x86_64-apple-darwin10.8.0/3.1.1",
        production="packages"
    )
)
```

then just

```
config$lib.path[[config$status]]
```

will work